# How do you safely identify a user contacting our API via an intermediary platform?

Tags: security, authentication, design-patterns, blockchain, identity

Our users create orders via an external online platform. This online platform sends our API any orders created by our users. How can we safely ensure that these orders were created by the user the online platform says?

We are investigating sending an authentication challenge for each order received via email/sms. This could become tiresome for operators creating orders all day though. What is the ideal pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Security, including non-repudiation concerns, is a question of striking a balance between safety and convenience. The more secure you make a system, the more inconvenient it becomes, and vice versa.

A sufficiently secure system could be so inconvenient that it scares away users. Thus, security analysis and threat modelling should involve both technical and business stakeholders. Making a maximally secure system that no-one wants to use solves no problems if your company goes out of business from lack of customers.

The OP concern about order verification via email or SMS is a good example of this conundrum.

Specifically regarding order verification, you *might* consider a 'batching' feature where super users can create batches of orders that they only have to verify with a single SMS or email.

The disadvantage of that idea is that you run the risk of users misunderstanding how the feature works. If it's unclear to users that they have to submit the batch at the end of the working day, they may believe that they've submitted many orders, where in fact, they've submitted none.

This strikes me as mostly a UX problem, more than a technical problem.

Another option is to ask each user to sign their orders using [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). Users should sign with their private key, but this again becomes a usability and infrastructure challenge.

Work with all stakeholders to find an acceptable solution that solves the right problems.